# Android ScrollView not working properly when use toolbar

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview, android-xml, android-scrollview

I developed an android application in which the scroll-view is not scrolling.. I am posting the code here pls check and if found any error pls help.. Here I used RelativeLayout as root and then Scroll-view and Relative Layout inside the scroll-view and ... Edit text ans Spinner inside relative layout... but this is not scrolling up..

This is my XML :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/white">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
        layout="@layout/app_bar" />
</LinearLayout>

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:layout_above="@+id/btnAccept"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ll1"
   >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rel_input"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txvPanmain"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="WANT TO GET IN TOUCH WITH US?"
            android:textColor="#131517"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/floatedtFullName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txvPanmain"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edtFullName"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:hint="Full Name"
                android:inputType="textCapSentences"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textColorHint="#ff0000"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinCountry"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/floatedtFullName"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:entries="@array/country"
            android:prompt="@string/addressProof" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/vspincountry"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0.5dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/spinCountry"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:background="#000000" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinCity"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/vspincountry"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:entries="@array/country"
            android:prompt="@string/addressProof" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/vspincity"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0.5dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/spinCity"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:background="#000000" />


        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/float_edit_email"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/vspincity"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edtEmail"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:hint="Email id"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textColorHint="#A4A4A4"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>


        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/float_edit_mobileno"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/float_edit_email"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edtMobile"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:hint="Mobile no."
                android:inputType="phone"
                android:maxLength="10"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textColorHint="#A4A4A4"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>


        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinFeedback"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/float_edit_mobileno"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:entries="@array/country"
            android:prompt="@string/addressProof" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/vspinFeedback"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0.5dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/spinFeedback"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:background="#000000" />


        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/float_edit_comments"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/vspinFeedback"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edtComments"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:hint="Comments"
                android:lines="3"
                android:maxLines="3"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textColorHint="#A4A4A4"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>



    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnAccept"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/red"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="SUBMIT"
        android:textColor="@color/white_color"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="normal" />


<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progress"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:visibility="gone" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is my app_bar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/app_bar_top_padding"
app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
app:theme="@style/Base.ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:textSize="22sp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:text="Toolbar Title" />
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: can you add code of app_bar layout?

Comment: please add the code of app_bar layout

Comment: check app_bar layout

Comment: I think you need to add LinearLayout between your ScrollView and your RelativeLayout. And close your </> Toolbar in your app_bar layout.

Comment: @Amardeepvijay your xml seems to work for me its scrolling properly. 1) you missed to put ending tag of RelativeLayout in your XML layout. 2) you can provide little more marginTop to each widgets. because you might be trying on different size of devices so there is possibility to not scroll, try on some small screen device like 5" devices...

Comment: not working, when keyboard is open scroll view does not work

Answer (score 1):

Your ScrollView has to be a defined height. Try `match_parent` instead of `wrap_content`. When a ScrollView wraps its contents there is nothing beeing clipped of you might be able to scroll to.

Comment: Do you see btnAccept and the ProgressBar when the App is running?